# Not null object but empty json

Tags: json, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS method that returns me a List with DO's. Unfortunetly when I go to the path which is mapped by the method i get only an empty json list like:

```
[{}, {}, {}]
```

My resource method looks like this:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public List<ModelDO> getModels() {
    List<ModelDo> models = modelRepo.findAllModelsWithName("Name");
    return models;
}
```

I'm 100% sure the objects exists and the list isn't empty, because I have checked it in the debugger.

The ModelDO class is a simple POJO:

```
public class ModelDO {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    //public getters
}
```

What should I do to get an non empty json response? 
PS. When I'm returning a single object I get the same problem -> {}

EDIT:

modelRepo:

```
public List<ModelDO> findAllModelsWithName(String name){
    return new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager).selectFrom(modelEntity)
                                       .where(modelEntity.name.eq(name))
                                       .fetch();
}
```

ModelRepo.class is @Injected into my Resoure class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that my Model object did not have field setters, only getters.